# Filling blank field in a DataFrame with previous field value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working with Scala and Spark and I am relatively new to programming in Scala, so maybe my question has a simple solution.

I have one DataFrame that keeps information about the active and deactivate clients in some promotion. That DataFrame shows the Client Id, the action that he/she took (he can activate or deactivate from the promotion at any time) and the Date that he  or she took this action. Here is an example of that format:

Example of how the DataFrame works
[image: Example of how the DataFrame works]

I want a daily monitoring of the clients that are active and wish to see how this number varies through the days, but I am not able to code anything that works like that.

My idea was to make a crossJoin of two Dataframes; one that has only the Client Ids and another with only the dates, so I would have all the Dates related to all the Client IDs and I only needed to see the Client Status in each of the Dates (if the Client is active or desactive). So after that I made a left join of these new Dataframe with the DataFrame that related the Client ID and the events, but the result is a lot of dates that have a "null" status and I don't know how to fill it with the correct status. Here's the example:

Example of the final DataFrame
[image: Example of the final DataFrame]

I have already tried to use the lag function, but it did not solve my problem. Does anyone have any idea that could help me?

Thank You!

Comment: Hi. Not sure how DF with clientid only, helps.

Comment: so what is the correct status?

Comment: The correct status is the last value different of Null for each Cliente ID. For example, for ID 1 the dates "03-13" and "03-14" should be "activate" in column "action" because the value for "03-12" is that one

Comment: handy to show an example but i will present a solution tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly expensive operation due to Spark SQL having restrictions on correlated sub-queries with <, <= >, >=.

Starting from your second dataframe with NULLs and assuming that large enough system and volume of data manageable:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

// My sample input
val df  = Seq( 
  (1,"2018-03-12", "activate"),
  (1,"2018-03-13", null),
  (1,"2018-03-14", null),
  (1,"2018-03-15", "deactivate"),
  (1,"2018-03-16", null),
  (1,"2018-03-17", null),
  (1,"2018-03-18", "activate"), 
  (2,"2018-03-13", "activate"), 
  (2,"2018-03-14", "deactivate"), 
  (2,"2018-03-15", "activate") 
 ).toDF("ID", "dt", "act")
//df.show(false)

val w = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy(col("dt").asc)
val df2 = df.withColumn("rank", dense_rank().over(w)).select("ID", "dt","act", "rank") //.where("rank == 1")
//df2.show(false)

val df3 = df2.filter($"act".isNull)
//df3.show(false)

val df4 = df2.filter(!($"act".isNull)).toDF("ID2", "dt2", "act2", "rank2")
//df4.show(false)

val df5 = df3.join(df4, (df3("ID") === df4("ID2")) && (df4("rank2") < df3("rank")),"inner") 
//df5.show(false)

val w2 = Window.partitionBy("ID", "rank").orderBy(col("rank2").desc)
val df6 = df5.withColumn("rank_final", dense_rank().over(w2)).where("rank_final == 1").select("ID", "dt","act2").toDF("ID", "dt", "act") 
//df6.show

val df7 = df.filter(!($"act".isNull))

val dfFinal = df6.union(df7)
dfFinal.show(false)
```

returns:

```
+---+----------+----------+
|ID |dt        |act       |
+---+----------+----------+
|1  |2018-03-13|activate  |
|1  |2018-03-14|activate  |
|1  |2018-03-16|deactivate|
|1  |2018-03-17|deactivate|
|1  |2018-03-12|activate  |
|1  |2018-03-15|deactivate|
|1  |2018-03-18|activate  |
|2  |2018-03-13|activate  |
|2  |2018-03-14|deactivate|
|2  |2018-03-15|activate  |
+---+----------+----------+
```

I solved this step-wise and in a rush, but no so apparent.

Comment: It solved my problem, thank you very much!
Just for curiosoty, the function "dense_rank()" does the same thing as the function "row_number()"?

Comment: Yes, I do. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, need to work around a few nested sql limitations with spark sql. cheers